# Getutcdate() SQL Server ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Okay, this is probably a really simple answer, but I am curious as to why when I use `getutcdate()` in part of my insert string from a ASP.NET C# page into a SQL Server database, it is storing the values in the column (datatype `DATETIME`) as

```
9/23/2017 10:06:43 AM
```

When by Microsoft's own account, they should be stored and retrieved as:

```
2017-09-23 10:06:44.933
```

as listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getutcdate-transact-sql

Can someone please explain why it would be getting stored in the US format?

Thanks heaps for any light you can shed on this :-)

Comment: The `DATETIME` in SQL Server isn't stored in any format - it's an **8 byte binary data**. It's only ever converted to a string for **presentation** - and you can control that by settings in e.g. SQL Server Management Studio, or inside your own code

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @marc_s :-)